# replace handleEvent(Event e) by processEvent(AWTEvent e)

Tags: java

I can't find a way to transform the code when replacing the deprecated function`handleEvent` with`processEvent`. can anyone help?

how to get x, y and the id of the event on processEvent?

here is my function:

```
public boolean handleEvent(Event evt) {

      if (evt.target == this) {
        // move floatting text zone
        if (dragingTextZone == true) {
            this.posStr.x = evt.x;
            this.posStr.y = evt.y;
            repaint(this.posStr.x,
                    this.posStr.y,
                    1000,
                    (int) (_imageViewer.getCurrent_font().getSize() * _imageViewer.getScalefactor()));

            if (evt.id == Event.MOUSE_DOWN) {
                dragingTextZone = false;
                addTextToPicture();
            }
        }

        if (evt.id == Event.MOUSE_DRAG) {

            if (dragitem.isDragging()) {
                repaint(dragitem.getX(),
                        dragitem.getY(),
                        dragitem.getWidth(),
                        dragitem.getHeight());
                dragitem.drag(evt.x, evt.y);
                repaint(dragitem.getX(),
                        dragitem.getY(),
                        dragitem.getWidth(),
                        dragitem.getHeight());
            }
        }
        else {
            if (evt.id == Event.MOUSE_UP) {
                // setting crop zone
                if (dragingCropZone || dragingMask) {
                    endDrag(evt);
                }
                else if (dragingLine) {
                    addLineToPicture();
                    endDrag(evt);
                }
            }
            if (evt.id == Event.MOUSE_DOWN) {
                if (getEditMode() == EDTMODE_ALL) {
                    if (evt.modifiers == Event.CTRL_MASK) {
                        startDragHighLight(evt);
                    }
                    else if (evt.modifiers == Event.ALT_MASK) {
                        startDragLine(evt);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (clickedOnFocusedItem(evt)) {
                            startDragMask(evt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return super.handleEvent(evt); // This passess the mouse click back up to Applet
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Could you provide code samples of what you have and what you're trying to do?

Comment: There's a nice _edit_ button which you can use to edit your question and include your code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a single `Event` class that includes everything, the new (relatively speaking - it's been around since Java 1.1) `AWTEvent` approach is to have different subclasses of `AWTEvent` for different purposes.  In your case it's the `MouseEvent` subclass you're interested in, so you would need to call `enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK)` to enable handling of the relevant events, then override `processMouseEvent` and `processMouseMotionEvent` to do the handling.

But the preferred way to handle events is not to override the `process*` methods but rather to register separate *listener* objects.  In your case you would create another class (possibly an inner class inside your main one) which is a subclass of `MouseAdapter`, override the relevant event hook methods in that, then register an instance of the adapter class by calling both `addMouseListener` and `addMouseMotionListener` on the main component.

There is extensive documentation [on the Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) (and elsewhere) on how to implement event handling in an AWT or Swing application.

Comment: @user2274161 there are several examples at the link I gave in the last paragraph, and many other AWT/Swing tutorials elsewhere on the web. Stack Overflow isn't a place to get other people to write all your code for you - look at some tutorials, try writing the code yourself, and if you get stuck then by all means ask another question showing what you've tried and ask for help to debug it.

Comment: i was just asking for example not writing my code bcz im new in java. Anw thank you for your time and for your help. Regards